# How to graph relations between my models

Tags: django, orm

I am running the Google App Engine (v 1.10) using Django (1.2).  I have a folder of models that I would like to show all of the relations and objects in a picture format.  A good example would be the ORM from this site.  http://expose.pl/kurs-django/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with graphviz, there is a ready-made solution for Django models available in the `django-extensions` 3rd party module here:

http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/graph_models.html

...hmm, on second thoughts I guess you're probably not using Django models but rather App Engine datastore models (and not [NDB](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/) models judging by your old version). Try this:

https://code.google.com/p/appengine-modelviz/

I have used the django graphviz before with success, have not tried modelviz personally.